# GPU programming in a Flutter application?

Tags: flutter, gpu

I am learning [Flutter](https://flutter.dev/) and found it very interesting and responsive for developing cross platform apps especially for Android and iOS. I am considering it to develop my next app but it has some requirements to process data on GPU.

Does Flutter support GPU programming in any way? Can I mix code written for Open GL ES 3.0 or Metal into a Flutter app?
Searching on the web, I could not find any examples of GPU programming on Flutter.

Comment: No answers at all? I will take that as a "No". Maybe GPU programming support will be part of Flutter in future releases.. Its fairly new in the market. So its understandable that no GPU programming support is there "yet"? But upcoming in future releases maybe? I really hope that it gets supported in future since its such an excellent framework to build apps with.